# NZEC in Python 3.6

Tags: python, runtime-error

You have to take two inputs a(size of array) and b(number of test cases) and an integer array called stars.

But I'm getting NZEC for some reason for large values...

The common reason for this error is by not using the input() properly.

Let me show you the code for where I'm using input()

```
a,b = map(int , input().split())

stars = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

The input is separated by spaces so I used split()

And This works for all of the cases but when a and b both are of 10^5 and

the array "stars" also has size of 10^5 it causes some issue and results in NZEC?

I have not done divided by zero anywhere also.

I have already tried doing try: (code) except: pass (It gives me Wrong answer Instead of NZEC)

Is there any other cause for NZEC to appear?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for NZEC to appear is that in my code I did not properly use .append() part in the arrays I have declared stars1 and stars2

```
stars1 = []
stars2 = []
```

Mistake:

```
stars1.append(x,x-1)
```

we can't append two values!

correct way:

```
stars1.append(x) 

stars2.append(x-1)
```